# Media queries not working on MailChimp

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, desktop, mailchimp

I’m pretty new to CSS and I’m trying to add some customization to my MailChimp newsletters. My images have text so when I make them responsive and view them on mobile, the text is too small. I want to have 2 versions: 1 image that’s visible on desktop and a 2nd image that users on mobile will see. I’m using this code, and it’s working for my on my website, but not on MailChimp.

```css
<style>

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 0px)
  and (max-device-width: 720px) {div#banner {visibility:hidden;}}
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 720px) {
  #banner { display: none; }
  .mobile-hide{ display: none; }
}
  
  
  @media (min-width: 721px)
    @media only screen
   {div#deskbanner {visibility:hidden;}}
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 721px) {
  #deskbanner { display: none; }
  .desk-hide{ display: none; }
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="banner" class="fb-like-box mobile-hide"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0073/8132/files/bangkok-traveling-tailor-trunk-show.jpg?606649028080735558" alt="Bangkok Traveling Tailor Trunk Show" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"/></div>
<div id="deskbanner" class="fb-like-box desk-hide"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0073/8132/files/bangkok-traveling-tailor-trunk-show-mobile.jpg?4005121060620406786" alt="Bangkok Traveling Tailor Trunk Show" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"/></div>
```

When I view it on mobile, I see the mobile image like I’m supposed to. If I view the email on desktop though, I see both the desktop image AND the mobile image. I do know that you have to inline CSS styles on MailChimp and I've also read that media queries don't work well in gmail, etc., but is there a solution to this? If not media queries, what else can I do to solve this?

Comment: HTML emails are notorious for being flaky. The parsers are dated and don't support many of the new standards. See [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/) article. I'm not sure if CSS Media queries are supported, but you could try running your message through [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) to see how it will appear and to generate any CSS warnings for features unsupported in email clients.

Comment: @War10ck is correct. When creating HTML emails it's best to assume it's 1998. Tables for layout, deprecated HTML styles, inline styles, etc. Your best bet is to call Mail Chimp customer support.

Comment: Thanks for your input. MailChimp support told me it is possible but I would need to ask a programmer for help as they're not coding experts. I guess I will just have to adjust my image. Thanks again!

Comment: I would avoid using two different images with show/hide. Gmail doesn't seem to like this approach and shows both.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with something like this:

```
...
<style>

td.mobile, img.mobile, td.spacer {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {


img[class=mobile], td[class=mobile] {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    line-height: 21px !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}

}
</style>
...
td[class=hide], span[class=hide], table[class=hide], img[class=hide] {display:none !important;    width:0 !important;}

                    <td bgcolor="#faf8ec" class="mobile" style="width: 0;overflow: hidden;display: none;visibility: hidden;line-height: 0;padding: 0;margin: 0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="main480.jpg" alt="Holiday Tables" width="310" class="mobile" style="width:0; overflow:hidden; display:none;visibility:hidden;"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="310" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#faf8ec" class="w320" style="padding: 0;margin: 0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/main640.jpg" alt="Holiday Tables" width="640" border="0" class="hide" style="display:block; font-size: 23px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#444444;"></a></td>

...
```